# Trying a program in python for mapreduce and need some help in it

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

To get more hands-on experience I wanted to try a project word count.
Here is the sample data which I have.

> The United Nations (UN) is an intergovernmental organisation
>   established on 24 October 1945 to promote international cooperation. A
>   replacement for the ineffective League of Nations, the organisation
>   was created following World War II to prevent another such conflict.

[...]

and i used the following python code to get my result

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

from mrjob.step import MRStep



class MovieRatings(MRJob):

    def steps(self):

        return [

            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper_get_ratings,

                   reducer=self.reducer_count_ratings),

  ]



    def mapper_get_ratings(self, _, line):

        (word) = line.split(' ')

        yield word, 1



    def reducer_count_ratings(self, key, values):

        yield Key, sum(values)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    MovieRatings.run()
```

i am getting the following error with Python 2

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# python RatingsBreakdown.py UN.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RatingsBreakdown.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mrjob.job import MRJob
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 1106
    for k, v in unfiltered_jobconf.items() if v is not None
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also Python 3

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# python3 RatingsBreakdown.py UN.txt
No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
No configs specified for inline runner
Running step 1 of 2...
Creating temp directory /tmp/RatingsBreakdown.training.20171128.083536.602598
Error while reading from /tmp/RatingsBreakdown.training.20171128.083536.602598/step/000/mapper/00000/input:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RatingsBreakdown.py", line 25, in <module>
    RatingsBreakdown.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 424, in run
    mr_job.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 445, in execute
    super(MRJob, self).execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 185, in execute
    self.run_job()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 233, in run_job
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 511, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 144, in _run
    self._run_mappers_and_combiners(step_num, map_splits)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 185, in _run_mappers_and_combiners
    for task_num, map_split in enumerate(map_splits)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 120, in _run_multiple
    func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 662, in _run_mapper_and_combiner
    run_mapper()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 685, in _run_task
    stdin, stdout, stderr, wd, env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/inline.py", line 92, in invoke_task
    task.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 433, in execute
    self.run_mapper(self.options.step_num)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 517, in run_mapper
    for out_key, out_value in mapper(key, value) or ():
  File "RatingsBreakdown.py", line 13, in mapper_get_ratings
    (userID, movieID, rating, timestamp) = line.split('\t')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Also with my MovieRatings

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# python3 MovieRatings.py UN.txt
No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
No configs specified for inline runner
Running step 1 of 1...
Creating temp directory /tmp/MovieRatings.training.20171128.083635.368889
Error while reading from /tmp/MovieRatings.training.20171128.083635.368889/step/000/reducer/00000/input:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MovieRatings.py", line 20, in <module>
    MovieRatings.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 424, in run
    mr_job.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 445, in execute
    super(MRJob, self).execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 185, in execute
    self.run_job()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 233, in run_job
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 511, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 150, in _run
    self._run_reducers(step_num, num_reducer_tasks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 246, in _run_reducers
    for task_num in range(num_reducer_tasks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 120, in _run_multiple
    func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/sim.py", line 685, in _run_task
    stdin, stdout, stderr, wd, env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/inline.py", line 92, in invoke_task
    task.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 439, in execute
    self.run_reducer(self.options.step_num)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 560, in run_reducer
    for out_key, out_value in reducer(key, values) or ():
  File "MovieRatings.py", line 17, in reducer_count_ratings
    yield Key, sum(values)
NameError: name 'Key' is not defined
```

I would like to solve the error and understand what ny mistake is.

Comment: `key` instead of `Key` ?

Comment: You have an indentation issue in `steps()` with the trailing `]`, although it appears you might have several issues here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this library only works in Python3

```
  File "RatingsBreakdown.py", line 13, in mapper_get_ratings
    (userID, movieID, rating, timestamp) = line.split('\t')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

First, you ran `RatingsBreakdown.py`... Also, your shown input contains no tabs and you have tried to extract 4 columns. Not really clear what you expected here.

```
  File "MovieRatings.py", line 17, in reducer_count_ratings
    yield Key, sum(values)
NameError: name 'Key' is not defined
```

Self explanatory... your variable is lowercase `key`

Comment: I think wasn't able to answer it perfectly. will try to explain the question better next time. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying the examples in this course ([link](https://www.udemy.com/the-ultimate-hands-on-hadoop-tame-your-big-data/)) right?

According to this [issue](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/issues/1704), mrjob has dropped for Python 2.6.

How I fixed it is installing Python 2.7 ([refernece](https://myopswork.com/install-python-2-7-10-on-centos-rhel-75f90c5239a5)) on the CentOS the VM is using. Then set up pip ([reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4#configuring-and-installation)) and install mrjob again.

Everything works now by running this:

```
python2.7 RatingsBreakdown.py u.data
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the same but without using steps function. It worked.

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class wordcount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        (word) = line.split(' ')
        yield word, 1

    def reducer(self,x,count):
        yield x,sum(count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  wordcount.run()
```